# Preload SWF and Images

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

I have a flashbuilder project with a big image. The problem is that the default preloader does not load the images/swf's inside the project.

Is there a way to preload them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you embed the images into your SWF? The preloader will load the complete SWF with everything embedded into it, so I assume you did not embed the images. You can do that using the `@Embed()` notation in MXML, see [Embedding Assets](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flivedocs.adobe.com%2Fflex%2F3%2Fhtml%2Fembed_4.html&ei=uhLJS7-FBMH98AarkaiGBw&usg=AFQjCNE4m-l4gSLEaavmjuemAfo_NJR5LA&sig2=HNFuFXw4O46Y7o8d-LcIRw) for more details.